# Python How to burning discs with the monitoring of progress with IMAPI2

Tags: python, event-handling, progressmonitor

I'm writing the programm on Python with module for burning CD/DVD with IMAPI2.
I used these examples: [codeplex](http://csimapi2samples.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Dev/Main/Solution/MonitoringProgressWithEvents/Program.cs) and [comtypes doc](http://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/#com-events).

```
import comtypes.client as cc

class MyProgram(object):
    def main(self):
        # index of recording drive
        index = 0

        # files to transfer to disc
        path = r'D:\Example'

        # DiscMaster2 object to connect to optical drives
        discMaster = cc.CreateObject('IMAPI2.MsftDiscMaster2')
        # cc.ShowEvents(discMaster) ### uncomment for print events

        # DiscRecorder object for specified burning device
        recorder = cc.CreateObject('IMAPI2.MsftDiscRecorder2')
        uniqueId = discMaster.Item(index)
        recorder.InitializeDiscRecorder(uniqueId)

        # create an image stream for a specified directory
        # create a new file system image and retrieve root directory
        _fsi = cc.CreateObject('IMAPI2FS.MsftFileSystemImage')
        _dir = _fsi.Root
        _fsi.VolumeName = 'TestName'

        # create the new disc format and set the recorder
        dataWriter = cc.CreateObject('IMAPI2.MsftDiscFormat2Data')
        # cc.ShowEvents(dataWriter) ### uncomment for print events
        dataWriter.Recorder = recorder
        dataWriter.ClientName = 'MyClient'
        dataWriter.ForceOverwrite = True

        _fsi.ChooseImageDefaults(recorder)

        # get events
        sink = Sink()
        _events = cc.GetEvents(dataWriter, sink)
        # print(_events)  ### <comtypes.client._events._AdviseConnection object at 0x...>

        # add the directory and its content to the file system
        _dir.AddTree(path, False)

        # create an image from the file system
        _result = _fsi.CreateResultImage()
        _stream = _result.ImageStream

        # write disc using the specified recorder
        print('Writing content to disc...')
        dataWriter.Write(_stream)
        print('Finished writing content')
```

Create a custom class with method named as event of 'dataWriter':

```
class Sink(object):
    def DDiscFormat2DataEvents_Update(self, this, progress):
        strTimeStatus = 'Time: ' + progress.ElapsedTime + ' / ' + progress.TotalTime
        print(strTimeStatus)
```

And run this script:

```
prog = MyProgram()
prog.main()
```

I can write CD/DVD, but can't monitor a progress and I can't understand, why.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your translation of the C# class into Python is incorrect. For starters the `main()` method in your version only has one statement in it, `index = 0`. Secondly, the way your code handles events is completely unlike how it's done in the C# version which uses a call-back function — and it's hard to see how you'd expect a single call to `cc.GetEvents()` to possibly replace such a mechanism.

Comment: I apologize, didn't follow tabulation. I will edit.